# Natale con i tuoi e Pasqua con chi vuoi

Tags: phrase-origin, proverbs

Da dove deriva questo detto popolare molto comune?

Secondo [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Natale%20con%20i%20tuoi%2C%20Pasqua%20con%20chi%20vuoi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNatale%20con%20i%20tuoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPasqua%20con%20chi%20vuoi%3B%2Cc0) si è diffuso dagli anni '50.

Answer (score 3):

Non sono note, per quanto io sappia, le origini di questo proverbio.
Si può, tuttavia, ipotizzare che sia stato coniato come compromesso per conciliare i desideri delle generazioni più giovani con le usanze imposte dalla religione.
Infatti, Natale e Pasqua sono due delle festività più importanti e, pertanto, era tradizione trascorrerle in famiglia in modo quasi solenne. Con il tempo, però, è diminuita l'importanza attribuita dalla società a queste due feste, pertanto è pressochè caduto "l'obbligo morale" a riunirsi con la famiglia durante questi periodi. Essendo Natale considerato gerarchicamente più importante della Pasqua, sarebbe nato così il compromesso "Natale con i tuoi e Pasqua con chi vuoi"

Comment: La tua supposizione ha senso, specialmente per il fatto che il modo di dire si è  cominciato a diffondere  durante gli anni del boom economico in Italia. Forse qualche pubblicità dell'epoca?

Comment: Certamente negli anni del boom economico è cambiato radicalmente il rapporto tra la società e le tradizioni religiose. Personalmente non conosco le pubblicità degli anni '50, magari qualcuno più anziano può aiutarci!

Comment: Be', non ci sarebbe discussione che Pasqua è molto più importante di Natale, dal punto di vista cattolico. Ma Pasqua è in primavera…